# Check only string and only digits with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I would like to check if a variable has only alphabets (a-z) and another variable will contains only digits. So, I used `matches("[0-9]+")` to check only digits and `matches("[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)*")` to check only alphabets which can be lower or upper case. However, those regex are not working for digit and alphabets mixture. Like `aa2` and `2aa`. What I am doing wrong? What will be the correct way to check strictly alphabets and digits?

Comment: Use `find()`...

Comment: can you provide the acceptable and some non acceptable inputs for you?